# Page not routing to new page when clicked on anchor tag in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm writing a login form by using `laravel php framework`. Here is the code:
**`Login code`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
    <style>
        @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);

        body {
            margin:0;
            font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
            text-align:center;
            color: #999;
        }

        .welcome {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -150px;
            margin-top: -100px;
        }

        a, a:visited {
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 32px;
            margin: 16px 0 0 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome">
        <form action="POST">
            User Name: <input type="text"><br>
            Password: <input type="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
            <a href="register.php">Click here to register</a>   
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`Registration code`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
    <style>
        @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);

        body {
            margin:0;
            font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
            text-align:center;
            color: #999;
        }

        .welcome {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -150px;
            margin-top: -100px;
        }

        a, a:visited {
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 32px;
            margin: 16px 0 0 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome">
        <form action="POST">
            First Name: <input type="text"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text"><br>
            Password: <input type="password"><br>
            Email id: <input type="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`Routes.php`**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('/register', function()
{
    return View::make('register');
});
```

When I click on anchor link in `log in page`, it doesn't get redirected to registration page. But when I replace `localhost:8000` with `localhost:8000/register`, registration page opens.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your links points at `/register.php` what you want is `/register`. Just change that:

```
<a href="/register">Click here to register</a>
```

Or a much better approach, use Laravels helper function for generating URLs or even the full link:

```
{{ link_to('register', 'Click here to register') }}
```

Or if you aren't using Blade:

```
<?php echo link_to('register', 'Click here to register'); ?>
```

Most of the URL helper functions are listed [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls).
One important is missing from there though: `Url::to('your/url')` will just generate an absolute URL without the need to name your routes or target a specific controller action.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use URL::to() or route('routeName', $params) function if you're using blade change anchor's href like below

```
<div class="welcome">
    <form action="POST">
        User Name: <input type="text"><br>
        Password: <input type="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        <a href="{{ URL::to('register') }}">Click here to register</a>   
    </form>
</div>
```

Read the [routing documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code in login.php : your link points to "register.php", but should be "/register" according to the routes you defined.